# TeXLive Shell "Back end gone" error

Tags: texlive

I mostly use command line to work with TeXLive (portable installation) on Windows 10 . But when I launched the package manager (TeX Live Shell) found a "Back end gone" problem. After clicking "OK" the window closes.

I found this problem back on TeXLive2023, in TexLive2024 it is still the same.

How can I solve this problem, where to dig?

[image]

Sometimes before the "Back end gone" window pops up I manage to enter some menu, then an error window will pop up:

[image]

Comment: The dialog says "Back end" not "Back and" as you write in the title and text. Beside this I would ask on the texlive list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What's a texlive list?

Comment: the mailing list: https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live